# How to access selected values in ASP.net template field drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, templatefield

I have a grid view in which i have two edit template fields both with list boxes in. I need to get the value out of DropDownList6 and use it in DropDownList1's SQL connection string. i have tried every thing that i have found on this but cant make it happen, if someone could help i would appreciate it hugely. Thanks (:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" autopostback="true" >
      <asp:ListItem>Any</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Central</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>East</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>West</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="roomCode" DataValueField="roomCode"  DataKeyName="roomCode" AutoPostBack="true">
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT roomCode FROM [Room2] WHERE roomID NOT IN (SELECT roomID FROM [BookedRoom]) AND park="  **THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE VALUE** ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The `**THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE VALUE**` is where you put a parameter, and add one of the type of `<asp:Parameter>` classes to `<SelectParameters>`.

Comment: are you sure that you dont wanna explore other options other than not using the control parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This is where you use a SQLDataSource ControlParameter [as from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From this site:

```
 <p><asp:dropdownlist
      id="DropDownList1"
      runat="server"
      autopostback="True">
      <asp:listitem selected="True">Sales Representative</asp:listitem>
      <asp:listitem>Sales Manager</asp:listitem>
      <asp:listitem>Vice President, Sales</asp:listitem>
  </asp:dropdownlist></p>

  <asp:sqldatasource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
      selectcommand="SELECT LastName FROM Employees WHERE Title = @Title">
      <selectparameters>
          <asp:controlparameter name="Title" controlid="DropDownList1" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
      </selectparameters>
  </asp:sqldatasource>

  <p><asp:listbox
      id="ListBox1"
      runat="server"
      datasourceid="SqlDataSource1"
      datatextfield="LastName">
  </asp:listbox></p>
```

Note the data source has a controlparameter linked to the drop down.